# What would the infinite sum of c^n/n converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, exponential-sum

I know for example that the infinite sum of $c^n$ can be calculated when $|c|<1$ as below:

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c^n=\frac{1}{1-c}
\end{equation*}

And that the infinite sum of 1/n converges to infinity. But what is the sum of c<sup>n</sup>/n?

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c^n}{n}
\end{equation*}

And would this depend on whether or not c is less than or greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: What does the ratio test tell to you?

Comment: Pedantic thing: as written that doesn't make sense, since the $n=0$ term isn't defined. But if you start at $n=1$ then it makes sense.

Comment: The first equality you gave is only true when $|c|<1$.

Comment: Assuming all the technicalities mentioned above, by other comments, a met, the answer is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I posted a hint to get you started, feel free to reply in the comments with your progress and I will be happy to guide you further as needed.

Comment: I removed the **divisor-sum** tag, as this question got's nothing to do with the divisor sum $\sigma$ function.

Answer (score 2):

You know that for $ c\in (-1,1),$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c^n=\frac{1}{1-c}$$

by integration over $[0,c] \subset (-1,1)$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{c^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\ln(1-c)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{c^n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that your sum is only valid for $n \ge 1$ since you cannot divide by $0$.

Here is one approach to calculating that. Let
$$
F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
and differentiate it within the radius of convergence to get
$$
F'(x)
 = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right]
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{x^n}{n} \right]
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}
$$
which you can sum as an ordinary geometric series and integrate back to get $F(x)$...

Comment: @Arthur typo, $F(x)$ but actually $x$ on the RHS

Answer (score 0):

Your first series' answer is valid iff $|c| < 1$.

Similarly, in this case, if $|c| > 1$, then the series won't converge. In fact, $c^n/n \not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

For $|c| < 1$, you have that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{c^n}{n}$ converges, by the comparison test.

For $c = 1$, the series does not converge. This is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

However, $c = -1$ *does* in fact converge. The sum is $-\log 2$. This is the [alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series).